# MVC3, Spark View Engine: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, spark-view-engine

I'm getting this error when I try to use access an ASP.NET MVC3 application using the Spark View Engine published to my local IIS 7 server.  I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692007/the-type-or-namespace-name-mvc-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web) and have already followed that advice, but I still get problems.  I also tried changing the *Copy Local* setting to *true* for the Microsoft.Web.Mvc DLL.  I never get this error with the Visual Studio debug server.  Republishing sometimes makes the error go away, but it comes back.

Where should I start looking to get rid of this problem?

Thanks!

```
<!-- At the end of my Web.config: -->
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**edit:** For clarity, the IIS server that I'm trying to deploy to is on my development machine.

**edit:** My _global.spark looks something like this:

```
<use namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
<use namespace="System" />
<use namespace="System.Linq" />
<use namespace="Namespace.For.Some.Code" />
<use namespace="Namespace.For.Some.More.Code" />
<use namespace="Namespace.For.Yet.Some.More.Code" />
<use namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
<use namespace="Namespace.For.Still.More.Code" />

<!-- Added after suggested answer -->
<use assembly="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>

<global type="string" Title="'title of my app'" />
<global type="SomeDomainObject" SomeVariable="Utilities.ApplicationUtilities.GetSomeDomainObject" />
```

Comment: Is MVC3 installed on your server? If not install it manually or include the relevant dll's via a BIN deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jesse.  This is using the same machine I'm doing the development on, and, like I said, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Do I need to install MVC3 into IIS specifically ?

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. I miss read part of you question. Since this is already your local machine then disregard my comment.

Comment: That's alright.  I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you referenced MVC from your `/Shared/_global.spark` file?

You can see the details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952982/1107)

Alternatively you can add the namespaces to your `SparkSettings` when you register the ViewEngine. This is what mine looks like:

```
var settings = new SparkSettings()
 .SetDebug(true)
 .SetAutomaticEncoding(true)
 .AddAssembly("Web")
 .AddNamespace("Web.Model")
 .AddNamespace("System.Collections.Generic")
 .AddNamespace("System.Linq")
 .AddNamespace("System.Web.Mvc")
 .AddNamespace("System.Web.Mvc.Html");
```

Hope that helps,
Rob

Comment: I made the change posted above, and that *seems* to be working.  Since the problem has been intermittent, I'll see how it goes for the day.

The line I added is `<use assembly="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>`, and I added directly to the _global.spark file in my IIS directory.